# Intellij play-services-ads problems with implementation

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea

I'm new to Kotlin. I just have jumped from C++ straight to Kotlin one week ago, without any knowledge of Java, VMs etc. I made few simple apps like incremental game. They have worked fine.

So I started to try implement Admob ads to my app. And here I have a problem. When I tried to implement com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:22.1.0. in dependencies of build.gradle, it returned me errors:

```
\/Build appx: failed
   For every task error is

Error Execution failed for task 'task'
> Could not resolve all files for configuration 'app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform lifecycle-runtime-2.5.1.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.5.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Could not download lifecycle-runtime-2.5.1.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.5.1): No cached version available for offline mode.


(Those Tasks Failed)
  :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
  :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths
  :app:mergeDebugResources
  :app:processDebugMainManifest
  :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
  :app:checkDebugAndroidTestAarMetadata
```

I doesn't have stabile internet connection in my PC. Only access I have to internet is from my phone data transfer. I cannot download so much data. I don't know exactly what is happening. Did I need to download something? Here is whole build.gradle:

```
plugins{
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
android{
namespace ,com.example.gamegame'
compileSdk 33

defaultConfig{
applicationId "com.example.gamegame"
minSdk 16
targetSdk 31
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes{
release{
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
}}
compileOptions{
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions{
jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

dependencies{
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
Implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation androidx.constaintlayout:constaintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:22.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

I even created new project and followed everything in this guide https://youtu.be/vRqb-ZDe45A and happens same thing.